# Displaying simple message to index method in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need to add a warning message  / a notice  when the index page is displayed.
How can I do this ?
My current index method is this :

```
  def index
   @routes = Route.all
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

On your controller

```
def index
  @routes = Route.all
  flash[:notice] = "text for the warning message / a notice"
end
```

and on view

```
- flash.each do |val|
  =val
```